# Selenium Python StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to download all the pdf on a webpage using Selenium Python with Chrome as browser but every time the session ends with this message:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933
```

This is the code:

```
def download_pdf(self):
    current = self.driver.current_url        
    lista_link_temp = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
    for link in lista_link_temp:
        if "pdf+html" in str(link.get_attribute("href")):
            tutor = link.get_attribute("href")
            self.driver.get(str(tutor))
            self.driver.get(current)
```

Please help me.. I've just tried lambda, implicit and explicit wait

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you call `self.driver.get()` in your loop, all the other elements in the list of elements will become stale. Try collecting the `href` attributes from the elements first, and then visiting them:

```
def download_pdf(self):
    current = self.driver.current_url
    lista_link_temp = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
    pdf_hrefs = []

    # You could do this part with a single line list comprehension too, but would be really long...
    for link in lista_link_temp:
        href = str(link.get_attribute("href"))
        if "pdf+html" in href:
            pdf_hrefs.append(href)
    for h in pdf_hrefs:
        self.driver.get(h)
        self.driver.get(current)
```

Comment: @LBdoc Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

You get stale element when you search for an element and before doing any action on it the page has changed/reloaded.

Make sure the page is fully loaded before doing any actions in the page.

So you need to add first a condition to wait for the page to be loaded an maybe check all requests are done.

Comment: Thanks..I tried to use implicit and explicit wait without success..I tried even with time.sleep in order to wait for page load..

Comment: You are right that the elements are stale because they have been reloaded, but as far as I know it is not a matter of waiting for the items to load; once the go stale you must `find_*` them again.